# Bulk price and quantity update using rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, bulk-products-update

How to update **price and quantity** in **bulk** using **rest api**, provide us the process to update in bulk using rest api.

Single price and quantity is updated using rest api, but i need to update in bulk using rest api.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a CE feature!

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/bulk-endpoints.html

simply use `async/bulk` before your endpoint URL

then provide your payloads as an array

### Example:

Synchronous route: PUT /V1/products/:sku/media/:entryId

Asynchronous route/Bulk: PUT async/bulk/V1/products/bySku/media/byEntryId

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used this endpoint to update base prices:
*//www.your-website.com/{optional_store_view_to_update}/rest/async/bulk/V1/products/base-prices*

Your json object should look like this:

```
[
        {
        "prices":
            [
                {
                    "price": 12,
                    "store_id": 1,
                    "sku": "yyyy"
                },
                {
                    "price": 11,
                    "store_id": 1,
                    "sku": "xxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The same should apply to inventory:
*//www.your-website.com/{optional_store_view_to_update}/rest/async/bulk/V1/**inventory/source-items***